# Using the attributes of an external JSON file

Tags: jquery, json, getjson, each, drawimage

I get an "Uncaught TypeError" on a drawImage command because the picture's url isn't extracted correctly, I assume. The paths of the pictures are correct (their folder is in the same folder as the JavaScript file). How does one refer to individual attributes from a JSON file?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the JSON:

```
{
    "characters": [
        {
            "greekName": "Zeus",
            "romanName": "Jupiter/Jove",
            "description": "",
            "picUrl": "pics/zeus.jpg"
        },
        {
            "greekName": "Hera",
            "romanName": "Juno",
            "description": "",
            "picUrl": "pics/hera.jpg"
        },
        {
            "greekName": "Poseidon",
            "romanName": "Neptune",
            "description": "",
            "picUrl": "pics/poseidon.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

Relevant html:

```
    <canvas id="slideshow" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Here is the relevant .js code:

```
var aImages = [];
canvas = document.getElementById('slideshow');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

 $(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("c.json?callback=?", function (data) {  
        $.each(data.characters, function (i, item) {
            var oImg = new Image();
            oImg.src = item.picUrl;
            aImages.push(oImg);
        }
    );
    });
});

ctx.drawImage(aImages[iCurSlide], 0, 0);
```

Comment: are you reading json from an external file???

Comment: Yes, c.json is my external file.

Answer (score 0):

Put `ctx.drawImage(aImages[iCurSlide], 0, 0);` inside of `getJSON` callback.

```
var aImages = [];
canvas = document.getElementById('slideshow');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

$(document).ready(function () {
    // get json
    $.getJSON("c.json?callback=?", function (data) {  
        $.each(data.characters, function (i, item) {
            var oImg = new Image();
            oImg.src = item.picUrl;
            aImages.push(oImg);
        });
        // aImages is an array with elements
        // go for each element from array, and draw it.
        for (var i in aImages) {
            ctx.drawImage(aImages[i], 0, 0);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but suddenly it cannot find the file if I do that ("Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404"). The original error remains.

Comment: @annioid Maybe you need absolute paths for images. For example: `/pics/zeus.jpg`

Comment: Nothing changes, unfortunately.

Comment: @annioid Please create a JSFiddle with the issue.

Comment: I'm not familiar with JSFiddle, how does one add the json file?